# Rails Swagger-UI can't read swagger JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, swagger-ui, grape-api

I've been tried a lots ways, but I just stuck here.

Grape API can do `post` and `get` perfectly, but the swagger-ui encountered some problems.

I put `swagger-ui` in public folder, when I open it. It threw

```
Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:3000/v1/doc
```

Here is **api.rb**

```
module FruitAPI
  class API < Grape::API 
    version 'v1', using: :header, vendor: 'fruit_api'
    format :json
    prefix :api
    ...
    add_swagger_documentation(
      basd_path: "/v1",  #Swagger的base url
      mount_path: 'doc', 
      info: {
        title: 'Fruit API', 
        description: "A description of the API."
        },
        hide_documentation_path: true,
        hide_format: true,
        include_base_url: true
        )
  end
end
```

Comment: have you try to run `rails swagger:docs`